# impossible to access get vars in the controller

Tags: typo3, extbase

I want to access get vars (or maybe post vars) in the controller of an extbase extension. I use TYPO3 7.6.12

This is the code in my controller:

```
public function showAction(\Test\MdIframe\Domain\Model\Iframe $iframe = NULL)
{
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($_REQUEST);
    $args = $this->request->getArguments();
    print_r($args);
```

The debug function works, I get a filled array but `$args` remains an empty array.

Why? Has somebody an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `$this->request->getArguments` you only get Arguments defined by the action and passed by `?tx_myextension_plugin[argument]=value` (`f:link.action` put his arguments passed automaticaly to this prefix):

```
public function showAction($item = 12, $short = false)
{
  print_r($this->request->getArguments());
}
```

will outputs like this:

```
Array
(
    [item] => 12
    [short] => false
)
```

If you want to access global _GET vars you can use `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('var');` to get `?var=value`

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you try to fetch must be in controller request context.
Your post data should be addressed to the controller like:

```
 tx_extensionname_pluginname[object][property]
```

If you use f:form in your template, FLUID will do this for you and your form and post data are in correct syntax.